# vectorial gets overlayed by background color

Tags: android, vector, android-vectordrawable

I get a strange problem with vectorials lately on multiple devices. 
Sometimes vectorial drawable gets half overlayed by the background color of an imageview or a background color of a layout like this:

[image]

Here is my vector drawable :

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:tint="#26AAE1"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
        <path
            android:fillColor="#FF000000"
            android:pathData="M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zM10,17l-5,-5 1.41,-1.41L10,14.17l7.59,-7.59L19,8l-9,9z" />
    </vector>
```

Has anyone had the same kind of problem?

Comment: attach some codes for better understanding the problem.
read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking question please.

Comment: Hi, I added more info, however there is no code. problem is with vectorial drawable that I added from Google's clip art icons.